# Identify tiny white connector

Tags: identification

I bought a nano ITX motherboard on ebay (a Smartyacoo DS-2019), to build a computer in a gingerbread cookie tin.
In the corner of the board there is a tiny (and I do mean tiny, overall about 7mm wide, fitting a plug about 3mm wide) white connector labelled 'PWR_BT'. I was hoping I could attach a power button there, but step one is finding a plug that will fit in this connector, and I'm stuck. Can someone help?

[image: connector for ants]

Comment: Could be a "JST" connector?

Comment: It looks like the Picoblade connectors I use on one of my PCBs. http://uk.farnell.com/molex/53261-0271/header-smt-right-angle-1-25mm/dp/1125373 Does it have 1.25mm pitch?

Comment: Yes! That looks bang on! Thank you so much for your help. :)

Comment: The PicoBlades I've seen don't have those "wing" things on the side.  It doesn't look like a PicoBlade to me.

Comment: If you look up the PN I linked, it does indeed come with the wings.

Comment: @TorsteinFiskvik  Sure way to find out would be to ask the eBay seller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in one of the comments, this does look to be a small pico blade (by Molex) style connector.  It looks a bit odd just because it has the covered flat SMT pins to the sides (gull wings).  These are often used to connect small rechargeable batteries, (eg: As in small in-home wireless phones).  The connector on your "mother board" might be for a small backup battery.   (The male plug part is also in the above link, though you also need to have the crimp pins to insert into the plastic plug piece.

Here is a similar link for the other connector listing the needed 50058 or 50079 crimp pins:    http://uk.farnell.com/molex/51021-0200/crimp-housing-1-25mm-2way/dp/889477 .  See at the bottom of the page where it shows both connectors, pins already crimped on wires, and even the bare pins).